# Flask send_file inline not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js

Generating a PDF report in Flask and sending the file to the client using:

`send_file(file,as_attachement=False`)

On the React JS end I have a function the handles the PDF file: Using Axios:

```
const receiveFile = (data) => {
    if (data.data) {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.data]));
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url            
        link.setAttribute("download", data.filename)            
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
        document.body.removeChild(link)
    }
}
```

The file gets sent without issue and the `receiveFile` received the data properly; however, my browser is set to open PDF files.  Instead I am being asked to download it.  How do I fix the code so the browser displays the PDF when it is received.